# .Net WebApi Ignoring Query Parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webapi

I have a .NET WebApi Endpoint . It takes in NO query parameters. Yet it still responds with data , when I give it query parameters. In postman I give it ({{base-url}}/api/v1/moratorium?state=IL) This can be very decieving to the consumer.  Why ? What do I need to do to make this return a 404 if given query parameters? Do I need to do something with routing.  Any help would be most appreciated. - Jason

```
[ApiVersion("1")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/moratorium")]
[ApiController]
 [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetActiveMoratoriums() {

        IApiResponse<IEnumerable<MoratoriumDto>> apiResponse = await _moratoriumService.GetMoratoriums(null, null, null, false, null);
        return apiResponse.ToActionResult();
    }
```

Comment: Why exactly do you want to return a 404 if the endpoint is hit with query params? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Your service makes a response independently from the passed query parameters.

Comment: @GeoffJames So this endpoint is for specifically bringing back all moratoriums. If the consumer puts a query string on their request  like '?state=IL' , I don't want them being deceived and thinking they got back only moratoriums for Illinois.

Comment: Why would the consumer be adding query params like that in the first place? Have you told them to? I don't get why they would unless they were under the impression they could do such a thing, somehow. Have you good documentation to guide them on how to/not use the API? Is this not sufficient? You can bend over backwards to try and create an "ideal" solution, but if the simpler solution is to tell them not to, more fool them if they try and fail.